# Custom Android WebView with a site

Tags: android, web, view, webview

Android noobie here, I am trying to create a custom Android WebView which will be part of a jar file. I want the web view to load a certain page when it is used in an app, I have the following code :

```
public MyWebView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init(context);
}

public MyWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(context);
}

public MyWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init(context);
}

private void init(Context context) {
    this.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    this.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(context), "JS");


    super.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/webviewcontent.html");
}
```

However I see 2 problems with it. 
1. When I go to the activity which uses this it complains about

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.webkit.WebView.getSettings()Landroid/webkit/WebSettings;
    at curbside.com.cvsexample.MyWebView.init(MyWebView.java:35)

2. When I run this app the page is blank nothing happens. However if I use a regular web view and then in the onCreate I do :

   ```
   webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
   webview.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(context), "JS");
   webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
   webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/webviewcontent.html");
   ```

It works as expected.. what am I missing. Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the fill MyWebView code and also the part of your Activity that uses the WebView?

One thing you shouldn't to is load the page while the WebView is still executing the constructor since the WebView isn't fully initialized yet, probably not causing your issues but it's a matter of clean design. Just do something like: new MyWebView(context).loadPage() instead.

There's no point in setting a WebViewClient if you don't override some of its methods.

Comment: What device do you run the app on? Android version? emulator?